limit the length of titles to improve readability?
Long titles make posts unreadable. Some people even include long error message in a title which makes a real mess of the post.  I often skip posts with long rambling titles altogether.
Should we have a rule that does not allow titles longer than ten words?

Incidentally, when you edit titles that are too long, you need to ensure that the edit doesn’t lose information.

Just look at this example: Separate default configurations and my own changes with a layered FS : /Data/etc/ upper layer in RO and /etc/ lower layer in RW? I immediately skip the post to save my sanity.

I, for one, don't think we should limit titles to ten words. I think the title can be a useful part of a good question, so I don't want to arbitrarily limit it.
Of course, a rambling title is not a good title, so if there's a way to improve it (or any part of the post), anyone should please feel free to do so.
